# Hadoop reduce side join using Datajoin

Tags: hadoop

I am using the folllowing code to do the reduce side join

```
/*
 * HadoopMapper.java
 *
 * Created on Apr 8, 2012, 5:39:51 PM
 */


import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
// import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
// import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.contrib.utils.join.*; 

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class DataJoin extends Configured implements Tool 
    {
        public static class MapClass extends DataJoinMapperBase 
            {
                protected Text generateInputTag(String inputFile) 
                    {
                        String datasource = inputFile.split("-")[0];
                        return new Text(datasource);
                    }
            protected Text generateGroupKey(TaggedMapOutput aRecord) 
                {
                    String line = ((Text) aRecord.getData()).toString();
                    String[] tokens = line.split(",");
                    String groupKey = tokens[0];
                    return new Text(groupKey);
                }
            protected TaggedMapOutput generateTaggedMapOutput(Object value) 
                {
                    TaggedWritable retv = new TaggedWritable((Text) value);
                    retv.setTag(this.inputTag);
                    return retv;
                }
            }
        public static class Reduce extends DataJoinReducerBase 
            {
                protected TaggedMapOutput combine(Object[] tags, Object[] values) 
                    {
                        if (tags.length < 2) return null;
                        String joinedStr = "";
                        for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) 
                        {
                            if (i > 0) joinedStr += ",";
                            TaggedWritable tw = (TaggedWritable) values[i];
                            String line = ((Text) tw.getData()).toString();
                            String[] tokens = line.split(",", 2);
                            joinedStr += tokens[1];
                        }
                        TaggedWritable retv = new TaggedWritable(new Text(joinedStr));
                        retv.setTag((Text) tags[0]);
                        return retv;
                    }
            }
        public static class TaggedWritable extends TaggedMapOutput 
            {
                private Writable data;
                public TaggedWritable(Writable data) 
                    {
                        this.tag = new Text("");
                        this.data = data;
                    }

                public Writable getData() 
                    {
                        return data;
                    }
                public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException
                    {
                        this.tag.write(out);
                        this.data.write(out);
                    }
                public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException 
                    {
                        this.tag.readFields(in);
                        this.data.readFields(in);
                    }
            }
        public int run(String[] args) throws Exception 
            {


                                Configuration conf = getConf();
                JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, DataJoin.class);
                                String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
                                if (otherArgs.length != 2) 
                                {
                                  System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>");
                                  System.exit(2);
                                }

                Path in = new Path(args[0]);
                Path out = new Path(args[1]);
                FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
                FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);
                job.setJobName("DataJoin");
                job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
                job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
                job.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
                job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
                job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                job.setOutputValueClass(TaggedWritable.class);
                job.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", ",");
                JobClient.runJob(job);
                return 0;
            }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
            {
                int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(),
                new DataJoin(),
                args);
                System.exit(res);
            }
    }
```

I am able to compile my code. When I run in hadoop I am getting the following error  with the combiner

```
12/04/17 19:59:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 27%
12/04/17 19:59:38 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 30%
12/04/17 19:59:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33%
12/04/17 20:00:23 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201204061316_0018_r_000000_2, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: DataJoin$TaggedWritable.<init>()
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:40)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$ValuesIterator.readNextValue(Task.java:1136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$ValuesIterator.next(Task.java:1076)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceValuesIterator.moveToNext(ReduceTask.java:246)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceValuesIterator.next(ReduceTask.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.contrib.utils.join.DataJoinReducerBase.regroup(DataJoinReducerBase.java:106)
```

The command I use to run hadoop is 
    /hadoop/core/bin/hadoop jar /export/scratch/lopez/Join/DataJoin.jar DataJoin /export/scratch/user/lopez/Join  /export/scratch/user/lopez/Join_Output

and the DataJoin.jar file has DataJoin$TaggedWritable packaged in it

I checked some forums and found out that the error may occur due to non static class. My program has no non static class!

Could someone please help me

---

Thank you Chris I edited as you said . I updated my code to take in two files. But I am getting same error message

I am getting the same message
INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2

the error is

```
     Status : FAILED
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at DataJoin$Reduce.combine(DataJoin.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.contrib.utils.join.DataJoinReducerBase.joinAndCollect(DataJoinReducerBase.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.contrib.utils.join.DataJoinReducerBase.joinAndCollect(DataJoinReducerBase.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.contrib.utils.join.DataJoinReducerBase.joinAndCollect(DataJoinReducerBase.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.contrib.utils.join.DataJoinReducerBase.joinAndCollect(DataJoinReducerBase.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.contrib.utils.join.DataJoinReducerBase.reduce(DataJoinReducerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:468)



{


    Configuration conf = getConf();
    JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, DataJoin.class);
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length != 3) 
    {
      System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <in1> <out>");
      System.exit(2);
    }

    Path in = new Path(args[0]);
    Path in1 = new Path(args[1]);
    Path out = new Path(args[2]);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,in,in1);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);
    job.setJobName("DataJoin");
    job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(TaggedWritable.class);
    job.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", ",");
    JobClient.runJob(job);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I tried with a small input and it works when I use 2 files. May be my previous input was wrong .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a default constructor for TaggedWritable (Hadoop uses reflection to create this object, and requires a default constructor (no args).

You also have a problem in that your readFields method, you call `data.readFields(in)` on the writable interface - but has no knowledge of the actual runtime class of `data`.

I suggest you either write out the data class name before outputting the data object itself, or look into the GenericWritable class (you'll need to extend it to define the set of allowable writable classes that can be used).

So you could amend as follows:

```
public static class TaggedWritable extends TaggedMapOutput {
    private Writable data;

    public TaggedWritable() {
        this.tag = new Text();
    }

    public TaggedWritable(Writable data) {
        this.tag = new Text("");
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Writable getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Writable data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        this.tag.write(out);
        out.writeUTF(this.data.getClass().getName());
        this.data.write(out);
    }

    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        this.tag.readFields(in);
        String dataClz = in.readUTF();
        if (this.data == null
                || !this.data.getClass().getName().equals(dataClz)) {
            this.data = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(
                    Class.forName(dataClz), null);
        }
        this.data.readFields(in);
    }
}
```

Comment: props for taking the time to answer this

Comment: Thank you very much CHris White for the detailed explanation . I also have another problem . I have two input files which have to be joined . When I give 2 input files the system detects i
    INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
but during the reduce job it gives array out of bounds exception . The program is supposed to join two files. 
I am now trying to write two mappers for each table to  be joined . Is that how it should be done ? Or is there a better way to read and process all the files in a folder.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: If you have multiple input files, use `FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, "path/to/file1,path/to/file2");`

Comment: Thank You Chris. I got the it working . My input file had a | separator instead of the "," that I usd in my coedand that somehow made things go awry

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is only working with Text, chaining the default constructor in TaggedWritable should do:

```
public TaggedWritable() {
    this(new Text(""));
}
```