# Hadoop reduce-side join doesn't work

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

When I try the same example shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201500/hadoop-reduce-side-join-using-datajoin), I see following output but it doesn't proceed any further.

Please advice.

My DataJoin.jar includes following libs:

- hadoop-common.jar
- hadoop-datajoin-2.0.0.-cdh4.0.0.jar
- hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar
- hadoop-datajoin.jar

Here is some code:

```
$ hadoop jar DataJoin.jar /user/cloudera/join/reduceside/inp /user/cloudera/join/reduceside/out    
14/01/10 12:00:09 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.    
14/01/10 12:00:09 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2    
14/01/10 12:00:10 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201401100935_0010  
14/01/10 12:00:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
```

Comment: Looks "hadoop-datajoin-2.0.0.-cdh4.0.0.jar" is using "cdh4.0.0" but other jars are not using "cdh4.0.0". Actually, cdh is not compatible with Apache Hadoop. You'd better using the same version of Hadoop.

Comment: did you try other mapreduce jobs? can them proceed?

Comment: Yes, i am able to run standard MR jobs (without join) successfully.

Answer (score 1):

a nice tutorial about reduce side join you can refer here [http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Reduce-side-join-in-hadoop-%3A-Data-analyses-from-different-types-of-data-sources]